# Number of pixels in RGB image

Tags: image-processing, pixel

can any one tell that ,how many number of pixels are present in RGB type of image is it height * width or height *width * channels.
I want to calculate bit per pixel(bpp) of an image so i need this information.

Answer (score 1):

The *number of pixels* is simply:

*height* × *width*

It's indepenent of whether the color of each pixel is composed from a single channel or from several channels.

If your image has three channels, e.g. a separte one for red, green and blue, each using an 8 bit value for each pixel, then you have to add them to get the *bits per pixel* (*bpp*) value. In the example, it would be:

*bpp = 3 × 8bit = 24bit*

But it does not affect the number of pixels.

Comment: suppose during image compression of a color RGB image i got S=compressed image in bits ,than what will be value of bpp.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand *S=compressed image in bits*. Compression does neither affect *bpp* nor *number of pixel*. And BTW: *number of pixel* cannot be used to calculate *bpp*; it just does not contain any relevent information to that end.

Comment: <bits per pixel> = <bits of compressed stream> / <number of pixels in compressed stream>.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I disagree. That's not how *bits per pixels* work. If you have an RGB image with 24bpp and compress it, it's still 24bpp. In your formula, *bpp* would change with the compression rate.

Comment: Bits per pixel is also used as a measure of compression. Just like MP3 files use bits per second.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: If you do that for images, your likely to cause confusion. As a compression measure, it's not helpful because the original image can have a bpp between 1 and 64. So what would a *compression bpp* of 3.2 tell you? Not a lot.

Comment: I don’t know, maybe Google a bit to see how people use this term in compression? https://www.google.com/search?q=compression+image+bpp

Comment: Yes indeed, it's also used as a compression measure. I've got quite some experience in image processing and have only ever seen it used as a quality measure. There's always something new to learn...